# How to force killing application when minimizing in Android

Tags: android, security, terminate

Right now I'm developing some kind of password manager & generator application and it is almost done but I'm facing a problem that seems a bit hard to solve.

In order yo improve the security of my app, I added a timer so if the user is under inactivity the app will close. Now I'd like to close the app every time the user want to minimize it (pressing the "HOME" button and the "RECENT APPS" button).

I've tried `onStop()` and `onPause()` but nothing works because every activity on my app when is replaced by another moves through the mentioned states. Since I can't use `Keycode == Keycode.HOME` how could I do that?

Comment: Why you can't use override `onKeyPressed` function?

Comment: As I've been reading I just cant override the home button. Android does not allow me to do that.

Comment: Yes, you right, my mistake. Does it possible to lock your app in onPause and unlock in onResume using any password typed by user mb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that all your activities keep track of their state in onResume() and onPause(): they can increment some static application-wide variable counting how many of your activities are visible.
When this count goes to zero, it means none of your activities are visible and you can do your cleanup.

The solution proposed by @Don Chakkappan is not good enough I think, as your activity can be reported as active even though it's no longer visible.

Comment: That's a very good idea. I'm gonna try it. And yes, that's my problem, the activity does onStop()/onPause() when I just move from one to another.

Comment: I actually added a VARIABLE++; on onResume(); and a VARIABLE--; on onStop(); and if VARIABLE==0 finishAffinity() occurs. Everything is working perfect. If the user pushes HOME button or RECENT APPS button, the app is closed. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Continuously check the Activity in the for ground from a service

```
          ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
          List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
          @SuppressWarnings("unused")
          ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
          Log.d(TRCU.LOG_TAG, "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
          String currentActivity=taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
```

Then you can finish() or stop Service according to the context

Answer (score 0):

The Android usage model tells you not to do that. You can disable all password generating/managing when going to background and re-enable it when resuming. This will also be much faster performance-wise than killing the application on pause.

Since your app is a security enabling application, all sensitive information should be inaccessible at onPause anyway, so this shouldn't impact the design too much.